# Testing a Java application but compiler gives Does Not Exist for package even though it does

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compilation, javac

I'm trying to compile and run the following application:

https://github.com/benrayfield/mouseSwarm

I compiled the class files, copied them to the same directory as the main program, and tried compiling it with this command:

`javac -cp . Util.java`

However, it gave me the following output:

```
import mutable.time.Time;
                   ^
Util.java:247: error: cannot find symbol
                paint(g, Time.nowNano());
                         ^
  symbol:   variable Time
  location: class Util
Note: Util.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
```

I'm not sure if there is an error with the code, or with javac, or am I doing something wrong compiling it?

Comment: *the same directory as the main program* Meaning that you didn't correctly place them in directories, such as `mutable/time/Time.java`?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- No, even if I use the structure given it gives the same output.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Oh wait, nvm, it seems compiling it from the root directory causes it to compile correctly.